# how to integrate Zend Framework MVC with existing site

Tags: model-view-controller, oop, zend-framework, integration

So I'm slowly tackling OO and Zend Framework and their MVC process in particular.  I have an existing website and web-based calendar application that was designed by me, but coded by a different person and done procedurally.

I understand that it will be very difficult for my application to ever be completely OO without a full re-write, and I'm fine with that.  I have a lot of updates and modifications I want to do in the future, so I'm wanting to start replacing some of the basic components (login, authentication. etc) now, and continue to learn as I go.

Again, I'm really a newbie at programming and OO.

What I'm wondering is if I'm wanting to incorporate the Framework, then would I just first drop my whole site into the /public folder of the Framework and then start pulling functionality out from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that is an excellent Idea. You will have extra work keeping your legacy headers and footers in sync with the Zend mvc layout, but it shouldn't be too hard.

You might consider putting your library classes in /library/ so they are accessible to both the legacy and the new zend code. This way you are treating the legacy stuff as an 3rd party external resource.

Good luck!

Comment: Well-luckily I'm not having to deal with Zend libraries being used in the old code, so that should reduce some confusion. :-D

Comment: You make a really good point about the headers and footers-I guess the shared header and footer layout stuff will be the first thing to tackle...